# Integer solutions of $3 a^2 + 12 a b + 11 b^2 - 1 = (a + b) (a + 2 b) (a + 3 b)$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

Are there integers $a, b$ satisfying $3 a^2 + 12 a b + 11 b^2 - 1 = (a + b) (a + 2 b) (a + 3 b)$?

If so, what is the name for such equation? Any reference greatly appreciated!

Comment: The right is cubic in $a,b$ and the left quadratic. It may fall under elliptic curves, about which some things are known re. integer solutions. [Above my level]

Comment: appears you could finish this one with inequalities.  Draw your equation in the x-y plane, a becomes x and b becomes y.  Of the three connected arcs, the middle one adheres to the line $x+2y=0$  and stays on one side of it. For the upper arc, half of it adheres to $x+y=0$  and the other half to $x+3y=0$  Backwards for the lower arc. Along the three lines, integer pairs can be located precisely, while one may show that  the six half-arcs do not intersect  the straight lines   outside a circle of radius 5 around the origin.

Comment: i see, integer shifts in the numerator:  one of the half arcs is between $\frac{1-x}{3}$ and $\frac{2-x}{3},$   similar   for all six half arcs

Comment: @Will Jagy : Thanks for the comments, I will think about it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the first question is no.

In order to simplify the equation, we perform the substitution $c=a+2b$ and get the form $b^2(c-1)=c^3 - 3c^2 + 1$. Since $c^3 - 3c^2 + 1=(c-1)(c^2-2c-2)-1$, we conclude that $c-1=\pm 1$. For $c=0$ one arrives at the equation $-b^2=1$ satisfied by no real $b$, while for $c=2$ one obtains $b^2=-3$, which is also impossible for real $b$.

Comment: Thank you! Just to spell out in more details for those who don't follow the "we conclude that" : rearranging we get $1=(c-1)(c^2 - 2c-1-b^2)$ with $b, c$ integers so each factor must either both be equal to $1$ or to $-1$.